# How do I convert the right of a lambda operator to a string?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

**Preface**

I know it's possible to grab a variable's name using a combination of reflection and expressions. However, is it possible to grab more than just the variable's name in the case of property/field chaining?

**Example Function**

```
public void DisplayVarName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression){
    MemberExpression memberExpression = 
        expression.Body as MemberExpression;        
    Console.WriteLine(memberExpression.Member.Name);
}
```

**Example 1**

```
string helloWorldStr = "Hello World";
DisplayVarName(() => helloWorldStr); // Outputs "helloWorldStr"
```

**Example 2**

```
Person person = new Person(){ Name = "Santa Clause" };
DisplayVarName(() => person.Name); // Outputs "Name"
```

**Question**

Is there any way to store whatever is to the right of the lambda operator in a string?

Example 2 would produce `"person.Name"` rather than simply `"Name"`

Comment: think you mean `expression.Body as MemberExpression` :-P

Comment: All that information is in there, if you're willing to get at it.  The `Expression` of the `MemberExpression` will be another expression that has `person` within it.

Comment: @Servy Yup, turns out it was all there. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the simplest way is to iterate on the `MemberExpression.Expression`

```
public static void DisplayVarName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    List<string> memberNames = new List<string>();
    MemberExpression memberExpression = 
        expression.Body as MemberExpression;

    do
    {
        memberNames.Add(memberExpression.Member.Name);
        memberExpression = 
            memberExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;                
    } while (memberExpression != null);

    memberNames.Reverse();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(".", memberNames));
}
```

Comment: This only works if the expression is nothing but the representation of a series of member accesses; if it's anything else then it won't work.  It also ignores the innermost expression.  In these two cases it's the closure object, but if you're expression *isn't* a closure then it's unlikely to work as intended.  If, for example, the innermost expression is a static variable, or a constant, then it won't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the entire body of the lambda as a string it's quite simple:

```
public void DisplayVarName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression){     
    Console.WriteLine(expression.Body);
}
```

Comment: This would output `"value(MyNamespace.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1).person.Name"`

Comment: @James Which is technically what that expression contains; that type is the representation of the closure.